# data transfer minimization problem

Tags: algorithms, graphs, network-flow

You have $2$ computers denoted by $C_1$ and $C_2$ and
$n$ missions $M_1,M_2, \dots M_n$.
Doing the $i$-th mission on $C_1$ (resp. $C_2$) costs $a_i$ (resp. $b_i$).
Moreover if you do $M_i$ and $M_j$ are done on different computers. you incur an additional cost of $d_{i,j}$.
I need to find an efficient algorithm that minimizes the cost needed to do all missions.

I know how to solve this problem if all $d_{i,j}$s are $0$.

I think the solution should use either flow networks or minimal spanning trees.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Create an undirected weighted graph $G=(V,E)$ where $V=\{C_1,C_2,M_1, \dots, M_n\}$.
For each $i=1,\dots,n$ add the edge $(C_1, M_i)$ of weight $a_i$ and the edge $(C_2, M_i)$ of weight $b_i$. For  each pair of distinct indices $i,j=1,\dots,n$ add the edge $(M_i, M_j)$ of weight $d_{i,j}$.

You are looking for a $C_1$-$C_2$-cut of minimum weight, namely a partition of $V$ into $A$ and $B$ such that $C_1 \in A$, $C_2 \in B$ and the weight of the edges in $E \cap (A \times B)$ is minimized.

Intuitively, $M_i \in A$ means that $M_i$ is assigned to $C_2$ and $M_i \in B$ means that $M_i$ is assigned to $C_1$.
To find $(A,B)$ you can use your favorite flow algorithm to compute a maximum flow between $C_1$ and $C_2$ in $G$.

Comment: thank you very nuch
if i can i ask
flow invlolves directes graphs, how do you direct it ?

Comment: Just replace each undirected edge $\{u,v\}$ with two directed edges $(u,v)$ and $(v,u)$. Any flow that uses both directed edges can be simplified to a flow that only uses one of them (meaning that it only uses $\{u,v\}$ in one direction).

Comment: thank you !
helped around 30 undergrads perpering to alg exam